# Understanding IF Logic in my code

Tags: c#

I thought I understood programming well enough to get the results I was looking for but alas this simply is not working for me.  I've reduced my code to a simple Console application for assistance.  The goal was to print out a 5x5 grid of 1's and 0's.  Actually, I wanted to create a random x and y value such as 2 and 1 and I call this EmptyX and EmptyY.  In this spot and only this spot, I should get a '0' printed.  In all other cells there should be '1'.  So it should be a grid of all 1's expect for the spot identified by EmptyX and EmptyY.  My code below, although works, puts zero's down the entire column and row.

Why is this happening? I keep looking at my code and it seems my logic is good to me but of course it is not.  How else can I make the grid with only a single 0 at the spot EmptyX and EmptyY?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int EmptyX = new Random().Next(5);
        int EmptyY = new Random().Next(5);
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                if ((x != EmptyX) && (y != EmptyY))
                    Console.Write("1");
                else
                    Console.Write("0");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Something like this with the 2 and 1 example:

11111

11011

11111

11111

11111

Comment: Recall the Boolean algebra. You want to print "0" if `x == EmptyX && y == EmptyY`. So either white it that way, or change `&&` in your code to `||`.

Comment: Also, you might want to use the same Random object for both EmptyX and EmptyY.

Comment: P(x) && P(y) == !(P(x) || P(y)) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Comment: My dear stackoverflow friends...thank you.  For the immediate, I made the changes to the logic part of my code and it worked.  I thought I was getting good at programming but apparently I have a long way to go as AND NOT OR logic is still a head scratcher.  I will use the debugging step feature and slowly learn that way.  Again, my sincere thanks to everyone.   Ivan, yes...changed the && to || and switched 1 to 0 and it worked.  Sentry...I went to that link..that is some interesting (and hard to understand stuff).  Zohar you are right...no need to make two Random objects I understand now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you have confused AND and OR in the context of NOT.  This is a very common logic error (as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824764/boolean-expressions-getting-mixed-up-with-and-or-logical-operators-and-how-th)).

If conditions, believe it or not, can mess up even experienced developers.  I have seen it happen (never intentionally) over and over to senior developers who aren't paying attention.  So, be reassured, you are not alone.

The best way to deal with complicated if conditions is to write [Ridiculously Obvious Code (ROC)](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/09/01/no-comment-part-3.aspx) where you make the point of the logic ridiculously clear by using obvious naming and maybe being a bit verbose with the code.  In most cases, drawing out the code a bit doesn't affect performance, because the compiler will optimize out the extra working variables and generate exactly the same [IL](https://www.dotnetperls.com/il).

So for example, instead of writing

```
if ((x != EmptyX) || (y != EmptyY))  //I fixed it for you
    Console.Write("1");
else
    Console.Write("0");
```

You could write something like

```
bool isOnEmptyColumn = (x == EmptyX);
bool isOnEmptyRow = (y == EmptyY);
bool isOnEmptyCell = isOnEmptyColumn && isOnEmptyRow;
if (isOnEmptyCell)
{
    Console.Write("0");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("1");
}
```

The above takes several lines more of code but is ridiculously obvious, and makes it much harder to goof up the combination of your logical operators.

If you find that the verbosity of the logic check makes your method [too long](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/long-method), you can extract the logic to a separate function.  In this example, I also use [guard pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) to simplify the logic even further:

```
private bool IsOnEmptyCell(int x, int y)
{
    if (x != EmptyX) return false;
    if (y != EmptyY) return false;
    return true;
}

//Main program
if (IsOnEmptyCell(x,y))
{
    Console.Write("0");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("1");
}
```

Again, rest assured this won't affect performance, as the compiler will automatically [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) your code when necessary.  The important thing is to focus on writing source code that is easy to understand and difficult to misunderstand.

Comment: Thank you John for taking the time to explain this to me and to provide me with code revision.  Indeed, I'm starting to understand.  I actually like the more verbose code as I can fully follow the "logic".   And I've also now learned about Guard patterns in programming.  Very nice answer to me.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry...I just had to thank you again for such a wonderful answer.  I do not use StackOverflow often but hope I have given you the necessary credit.

Answer (score 1):

your code will print 0 whenever

```
x=EmptyX or y=EmptyY
```

for example

```
if EmptyX =3 and EmptyY=3 and x=0 and y=3

  if ((x != EmptyX) && (y != EmptyY))
  if ((x != 3) && (y != 3))
  if ((0 != 3) && (3 != 3))
  if ((true) && (false))
  if (false)
```

and it will not print '1' when it should.
change your condition to

```
if ((x != EmptyX) || (y != EmptyY))
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your if else condition.

Method-1.

```
if ((x == EmptyX) && (y == EmptyY))
     Console.Write("0");
else
     Console.Write("1");
```

Method-2.

```
if ((x != EmptyX) || (y != EmptyY))
        System.out.print("1");
else
        System.out.print("0");
```

Comment: Thank you Ashish.  Most helpful.